# How to respectfully "correct" my supervisor even though normally I'm the one who needs a lot of help?

Tags: phd, interpersonal-issues, health, emotional-responses

### TL;DR

I have made little progress in the time I started working as a PhD student (few months) and I need a lot of help from my supervisor (the professor). I get the feeling that I - or my lack of progress - is starting to annoy them. I sometimes have to correct mistakes in their emails, which makes me feel bad because I am only a PhD student and this makes me hesitate and question what the right approach for this is.

---

I'm a PhD student in a natural science in Germany. I started about one year ago and so far, I have not been able to produce any meaningful publishable results. I have only worked on reproducing already published results. The idea was that my own project would be build upon these published papers which were written by my supervisor (the professor) and their collaborators. My project is funded by an external funding organization.

Until about two months ago, I really enjoyed working on this project, even though I did not make any significant progress. However, back then it seemed as if there were only a few steps left until I can start working on my own results. That has changed and now I am quite disoriented. Of course *failure* is always an important part in science. However, normally I have at least some idea of where the problem is, for example in the code I use for numerical calculations. This is not the case this time. I have made thorough checks of every part and I don't find the problem. My supervisor is quite sure that the approach I am following should work and I also don't see why it shouldn't. My next idea would be for example to *politely* ask her to implement a simplified version of the code so that we can see if I have a bug somewhere.

Overall, they have been very kind and helpful so far. I feel like my performance was very bad over last months since I graduated. This is also partially due to mental health problems and the ongoing pandemic. I was seeking professional help for these problems but I only "made it" onto the waiting list of a psychotherapist and it seems I will have to wait. As an example, due to the pandemic, the transition between being an undergraduate and actually working as a PhD student and research assistant was so *unspectacular* that I don't really feel like I "made it", i.e. graduated.

I get the feeling that my supervisor starting to get annoyed with me. During a group meeting a few weeks ago, they sounded *exasperated* when I started talking about my (way to small) progress. They did not make any comments about my lack of progress in front of the others or told me about it explicitly, but I still got the feeling. I could not make out whether it was because of me and my failure or because of the problem itself since they were also trying very hard to help me and ultimately this problem was solved.

I am starting to get the feeling of "stepping on their toes" because of all the help I require to get it working. A few days ago I received a mail where they wrote something that was clearly wrong from a mathematical standpoint (in my opinion at least) and I thought about how to best respond to that so as not to upset or even anger them in the slightest way or to come off as supercilious. I am only working there for a few month and the topic is also new to me. Therefore, I am always afraid when "correcting" something as they as a professor should certainly know better than me who just started working on this topic a few months ago. From their response it was quite unclear whether they understood the problem.

There are three problems with this...

1. If I am correct when I correct them (or rather "make careful suggestions") I will definitely feel sorry for them because they thought that this would be a good method of solving the problem. In a way, the overall methodology is anchored in the project which was set up by them. Furthermore, I will now have to find a workaround for the problem at hand which is not that bad because I like working on the project but it would still be a small setback
2. If they were correct then I come of as somewhat arrogant if I am note careful enough especially since I am already way behind on progress.
3. If they don't understand what I mean or still think they are right even if they are not, I will have to "keep digging". This is the worst outcome because of the points mentioned above. My remarks that "what they write is wrong" would only come of as annoying.

As previously mentioned, a smaller part of this, such as discussions is part of "the normal academic process" and science in general. My personal problem is that I am feeling like "the new guy who is unable to get results and always needs help".

In summary, I guess my question would be, how to handle these problems properly. How much "necessary help" is normal and what would be too much?

Comment: Very long. Can you write a summary?

Comment: Sounds like you're making a lot of assumptions that should be tested by clear communication with your supervisor.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I added a short summary.

Comment: I got the impression from reading this that you started your PhD with a lot of respect for your supervisor, perhaps believing that due to their senior position they would not make mistakes in research. In fact, senior people can be wrong just as often as the less experienced, and there's nothing wrong or troubling about that, as long as the mistake and solution are clearly communicated. Overall, I agree with henning: all of this uncertainty can be resolved if you and supervisor work on your communication problems.

Comment: Also, it's impossible to be *way behind on progress* only a few months into a PhD. Wait until your seventh year.

Comment: Love it when a PhD student finds a flaw in my thinking and can communicate it clearly and effectively/come up with a better solution. This is a form of pulling your weight. The faculty member probably put 5 min into thinking about the problem so it is no surprise that you (who have been thinking more and harder about it) have a better take.

Comment: @henning--reinstateMonica Normally, PhD contracts are three-year fixed term employment contracts at my university which can usually be extended to five years. I don't know what happens when the cotract finally ends. Since it is bound to the project, I would assume that I would not be able to continue working on the project and have to find an alternative...

Comment: I see... not enough for an answer, but you do need to know how to debug your own code. Supervisor should not do it. Consider running it with sample data with known properties.

Comment: @HerpDerpington I know, I was speaking tongue in cheek. The fixed term contracts are a source of much real uncertainty. What I was trying to convey is that most visible progress only happens in the last year or so; the first half or more usually consists of trying to see through the fog.

Comment: You need to reframe your communication with your advisor. You don't "need to correct their mistakes". You need to discuss and develop their suggestions. For this you need to understand their suggestions. Ask for clarifications and if you believe you have a better and perhaps more correct alternative approach (great!), suggest it and ask them why they suggested their approach. If you believe you found a flaw in their approach, present your arguments. "You assume that the function is convex. According to the Finickle Theorem I would expect it to be concave. Why did you assume convexity?"

Comment: @Roland It was more something along the line of "1+1=3" where it was immediately clear, that something was not right.

Comment: @Dawn Actually, I would say that my technical expertise should not be the problem. The problems are more on the side of mathematics and transferring that into code. For example, I found a lot of smaller typos which leaded to incorrect results.

Comment: @HerpDerpington Your advisor should not even be involved in stuff as low-level as 1+1.

Comment: There are ways to do this without antagonizing your advisor, and you should not be scared about disagreeing with them. I wouldn't write an email along the lines of "your email is wrong since clearly 1+1 is not 3" -- that could come across as aggressive and put them on the defensive, and it could be there is some extra context you are missing. But you can say something like "I am having difficulty understanding the approach you suggest. Using the addition of integer theorem, I seem to reach the contradiction 1+1=3. What am I missing?" If you are precise and clear, they may enjoy the discussion.

Comment: Don't compare yourself to others or worry about being a squeaky wheel. Your advisor wants you and your project to succeed. You need help to make progress and it sounds like you have doubts. You need to clarify these doubts, whether that means getting your advisor to explain something you are missing, or getting your advisor to realize there is a gap that needs to be filled. All of this is completely, 100% normal and you are on the right track; just communicate openly with your advisor and don't let fear get in the way of clarity.

Comment: Also I would not read too much into things like "their tone seem exasperated" if they did not follow up in a conversation with you about your work. Professors are busy people and like anyone they can have a bad day and take out their bad day on you, even if they don't intend to and you don't deserve it. Also *you* are the one saying your progress is too small, not them; don't be so sure about your self-critical judgment. Research is very hard. Professors know this. Google "impostor syndrome" -- I (and everyone I know) suffer from this.